# Perl print switches in terminal

Tags: regex, perl, find, match

If I want to do something like this

```
      perl abc.pl > xyz.html
```

what command should I use so that I could store xyz.html into a variable. Im not allowed to change anything above, except the name of the html file

Comment: You want the terminal to print the literal `xyz.html` or its value?

Comment: literal xyz.html. I can add this file to the variable later to check for filter

Comment: Why not just `echo xyz.html`? Right after executing the perl command?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to obtain the literal file when i type in the above command so that I can work on the next step. Note: I mean that whatever I type  after the > sign is the file I want to work on later. I have already done the second part, just want to know how to solve this

Comment: I mean this perl script has to work for any files. If I were to echo, that would be like hardcoding it, which is what I do not want to achieve.

Comment: Write your Perl script to take the filename as an argument, instead of using shell redirection.

Comment: @friedo? May i see an example as to how i link that? Thanks

Comment: `perl -e 'print $ARGV[0]' jkl.html`

Comment: Question edited. I need to type in perl abc.pl > *name of my html file I want to stor*. Im sorry but I cant use mpapec as Im not allowed to use -e and 'print...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the light of your comments, you can do this but it is very ugly:

```
file=$(history | awk '/perl.*>/&& !/history/ {x=$NF} END{print x}')
echo $file
```

Basically it runs the `history` command to ask your shell for the list of commands you have run recently. It then uses `awk` to find all the ones containg `perl` and `>`. When it finds one, it saves the last word on the line (presumably the filename that you redirected into) in variable `x` and then at the end, prints out the last filename that any Perl script redirected into. Ugly but functional.

**HOWTO Debug problems with the above approach...**

To debug the script above, first try the `history` command on its own

```
history
```

and it should give you a list of all the commands you have typed. Now try `awk`,

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Hello"; exit}'
Hello
```

if that doesn't work, try this

```
awk "BEGIN{print 7; exit}"
```

and keep trying till you get `awk` to work, and see how the quoting works on Cygwin.

Then you should be abe to do

```
history | awk '/perl/{print}'
```

to see all the perl programs you have run and soon you will work out how to run my suggested code at the start of this answer.

Alternatively, you can do this which is MUCH CLEANER...

```
OUTFILE=xyz.html
perl abc.pl > $OUTFILE 
perl def.pl $OUTFILE
```

**Original answer**

Perl is totally unaware that it is writing into `xyz.html`, all it knows is that it is writing to `stdout` and the shell is directing that to `xyz.html` without Perl's knowledge.

If you are only saving a file for the next part of the process, why don't you send the output of your first program directly iinto the second one using a pipe, like this:

```
 perl abc.pl | perl secondProgram
```

then the second program can read from its `stdin` instead of from a file. This method has the advantage of avoiding the need  to create a temporary file.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your reply. You see, I am currently given an assignment where I have to run something like this: perl checkHtml.pl  < index.htm. I am not allowed to change the above as it does not follow my assignent. I am trying to ask how i can store what I type after the < sign into a variable, assuming the index.htm is stored in my files. Im running cygwin terminal.

Comment: I have added a new suggestion at the beginning of my answer, please look again.

Comment: Hi Sir, " ...and then at the end, prints out the last FILENAME that any Perl script redirected into". Does it means the name of the html file, or the value in the html file? Sorry, Im very bad in coding. Thanks. Im getting this error when I try to do this. perl p4task1.pl <  abc.html             where abc.html is one my current directory in cygwin. Please look at my error below.

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at p4task1.pl line 6, near "$(history"
        (Missing operator before history?)
String found where operator expected at p4task1.pl line 6, near "awk '/perl.*</&& !/history/ {x=$NF} END{print x}'"
        (Do you need to predeclare awk?)
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at p4task1.pl line 6, near "$(history "
syntax error at p4task1.pl line 6, near "$(history "
Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at p4task1.pl line 7.
Execution of p4task1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Ugh! You are on (useless) Windows, aren't you? Try changing the single quotes into double quotes.

Comment: Hi Sir, Im still facing the same error. And yes, if not for my assignment, I would have used Unix

Comment: Can you try the cleaner OUTFILE option?

Comment: Hi Sir. While I agree this is much cleaner. My assignment requires me to strictly use this format and nothing else : perl checkHtml.pl  < index.htm . Im sorry. Also, the above code you provided would only work for xyz.html. I need the script to work for any  html file extensions i type , where there will be a die function if it doesnt exist. Thank you

Comment: I have added some hints of debugging.